# Angular new router, html5 mode

Tags: html5, angularjs, html5-history-api, router, angular-routing

Не получается включить нормальное отображение url в angular new router.

In run application:

```
  $router.config.html5Mode = true
  $router.config.hashPrefix = '!'
```

In template:

```
   <div class="container">
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a ng-link="login">Login</a>
      <a ng-link="register">Register</a>
    </div>

    <ng-viewport></ng-viewport>
```

Пробовал также, не помогло:

```
@frontendApplication.config(['$locationProvider', ($locationProvider) ->
  $locationProvider.html5Mode = true
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!'
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее:

**JS**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) { //проверка поддерживается ли бразуером html5 history API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled:     true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    }
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
   // ...
   <base href="/">
  // ...
</head>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, вот только теперь перестали работать обычные ссылки, точнее их англуар тоже стал перехватывать=\

Comment: @Alliswell Насколько я знаю, нет смысла руками проверять доступность html5 history api, Angular делает это сам, автоматом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить `rewriteLinks:false`
Примерно так.

```
App.config (function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled : true,
        requireBase: false,
        rewriteLinks : false
        });
    });
```

p.s. Естественно не забывай про base url в разметке.